# Selecting a random orthogonal polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms, random, polygons

For a certain demo application, I want to create at random a rectilinear polygon with a given number of corners.

Selecting random $x$ and $y$ coordinates of each corner is not a good method, since most polygons selected in this way will not be rectilinear.

So, I thought of selecting $x$ and $y$ coordinates of each *second* corner. For example, if the random corners happen to be:

```
(0,0), (10,10), (20,20)
```

then I convert them to an L-shaped hexagon with corners:

```
(0,0), (10,0), (10,10), (20,10), (20,20), (0,20)
```

The problem is, this method sometimes yields non-polygons. For example, if the random corners are:

```
(0,30), (10,10), (20,20)
```

then the result is the following 8-shape, which is not a polygon at all:

```
(0,30), (10,30), (10,10), (20,10), (20,20), (0,20).
```

MY QUESTION: Is there a way to select $x$ and $y$ coordinates such that the result is always a polygon?

NOTE: The randomness is only for demonstration purposes. I.e, the polygons should be sufficiently random such that the user sees a different polygon each time, but it doesn't have to be uniformly random. So, if there is a way to select some numbers at random, and then modify them in some way so as to get a rectilinear polygon, this is fine.

Comment: What might be simpler than doing it with fixed numbers of edges is to instead do it with a fixed integer area. What I have in mind is along these lines: Start with a grid of unit squares, all blank except one. Then pick a random blank adjacent square to color in; repeating this $n$ times total gives you a set of $n+1$ connected black squares (with a total area of $n+1$) whose boundary is necessarily rectilinear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that instead of generating half the corners *in sequence*, I'd generate a bunch of overlapping rectangles (each defined by two of its four corners) and then define the resulting polygon to be the union of all these.

If the number of corners is a strong requirement, you might have to either loop or tune things towards the end to make sure it's actually met, since adding a rectangle can add up to four corners, but can even remove all but four corners, and anything in between.

Comment: Is the union of a bunch of rectangles always a polygon? I think it can result in several disconnected polygons.

Comment: @Erel: True, I should have written that the rectangles have to overlap. You might have to loop until that requirement is satisfied.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't save the need for looping... I was hoping for some way that generates rectilinear polygons with no looping.